# How to use Like to check if a match exists

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Am I missing something very simple or is this really not doable? I want to check whether str (which is simply one letter) is a vowel.

```
Dim testCheck As Boolean
testCheck = str Like [a,e,i,o,u]
If testCheck Then
    str = UCase(str)
End If
```

I was looking for a more elegant solution than looping through an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `Like` then use

```
str Like "[aeiou]"
```

`instr` might be more efficient though

Comment: I knew it was going to be something really obvious... just couldn't see it. thank you!

Comment: will award you the answer as it most closely matches my question.

Answer (score 3):

`instr(1,"aeiou",str)>0`   or you can use like x or like y or like z, for one char though, I'd use str=a or str=b rather than like